# Travel to Romania on Indian passport having Germany residence permit

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, romania, german-residents

I am an Indian and hold a German residence permit valid for 1 year. It expires in April 2017 and my Indian passport is valid until August 2021.

Can I travel to Romania with my visa issued by Germany (and my passport)?

Comment: did you go ahead with your plan? there is an important difference between a "German residence permit" and a "schengan visa". The key question would be what kind of visa do you have?

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you have a valid schengan visa you are set.

> Romania
>   Foreigners seeking to enter, transit and perform short-stays in Romania, can do that without needing to show national Romanian Visa, if they enjoy a valid Schengen Visa (type C, double or multiple entry). The allowed period of stay must not exceed the period of 90 DAYS within a 6-MONTH period and the visa must be used in the territory of the Schengen area first (For more and updated information please click here!).

source: http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/

Comment: A German residence permit is not a type C visa, and a residence permit holder is unlikely to have a valid type C visa, since the residence permit works like a visa.  Some countries (I don't remember which) offer exemptions to holders of type C visas and *permanent* residents, but not to temporary residents.  See, for example, http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66814/19400.

Comment: The situation is different. MK is non EU country. RO, as well as BG, HR, CY are EU countries and perspective Schengen countries (unlike GB, IRL, GBZ which are EU countries which are none Schengen countries.) RO, BG, HR, CY seems recognize Schengen documents.